# In Asp.Net, how would I determin which validator control has set Page.IsValid to false?

Tags: asp.net, validation, postback

I have a huge form with many `RequiredFieldValidator`s, how can I programmatically determine which control is setting the `IsValid` property of the `Page` to `false`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On the server side, you can look at the `Validators` property to find all the `IValidator` instances. Then, you just test which one(s) are not `.IsValid`.

```
var notValidValidators = Page.Validators.Cast<IValidator>().Where(v => !v.IsValid);
```

On the client side, it's similar. There's a JavaScript array `Page_Validators`, and each one has a `isvalid` property.

```
var notValidValidators = Page_Validators.filter(function(v) { return !v.isvalid; });
```

Comment: That looks promising but: 
`Error 17 'System.Web.UI.ValidatorCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.ValidatorCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Where is a LINQ extension method on IEnumerable. Make sure you have a "using System.Linq;". If ValidatorCollection doesn't support IEnumerable<T>, you can do something like Page.Validators.Cast<IValidator>().Where(...)

Comment: `Page.Validators.Cast<IValidator>().Where(v => !v.IsValid)` seems to compile, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can check the `.IsValid` property of the individual validators.

If it is a `RequiredFieldValidator`, the user should not be able to postback if the control is not valid anyway. What are you trying to do?

Comment: They all have `EnableClientScript="false"` and there are a bunch added programmatically as well. I have a certain instance of a form that isn't valid but an error isn't being specified, I'm trying to figure out which validator is triggering so that I can add a more explicit message.

Comment: For sure. You could go with Mark's LINQ solution, since that seems to be most efficient. I'm not too experience with linq myself.